# How to setup Facebook Payment API for physical goods/ products

Tags: facebook, api, payment

There are many detailed tutotrial avialable for Facebook Payment Integration for virtual currency and goods of a game. Is it possible to use Facebook Payment API for setting up store with payment options for physical goods?